# Assigning Values to an Array in a loop

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I Just started working on VBA excel. I want to assign certain values to an array but

I got

> Run time error '9'

```
Sub Getvalues()
Dim i As Long
Dim Arry() As Long

For i = 1 To Rows.Count
If Cells(i, 3).Value <= 1 And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
    Arry(i - 1) = Cells(i, 1)
End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: With a fixed size array you can specify its size at the start, otherwise you'll have to `Redim` it. I guess yours isn't a fixed size? Would you mind giving some sample data too? `Redim` on a larger dataset is going to be slow(ish).

Answer (score 0):

Since the data you want are Long type, you could try the `Split` function

```vb
Sub Getvalues()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim Arry As Variant, temp As Variant

    For i = 1 To Rows.Count
       If Cells(i, 3).Value <= 1 And Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 3).Value) Then
           temp = temp & "," & Cells(i, 1)
       End If
    Next i
    Arry = Split(Mid(temp, 2), ",")
End Sub
```

As **Davesexcel** mentioned, loop from 1 to `Rows.Count` would go through every row.

You could replace `Rows.count` with `Cells.SpecialCells(xlLastCell).Row` which only go through the row you used, not entire row.

Comment: Rows.count would be every row

Answer (score 0):

As per my comment, you'll need to either size your array at the start OR resize it using `ReDim` along the way. Downfall is that `ReDim` is rather slow on a large dataset. So it might be best to get a `COUNTIF` going to let you know before any loop how large your second array should be. For example:

```
Sub GetValues()

Dim i As Long, x As Long, Countr As Long
Dim arr1() As Variant, arr2() As Long

With Sheet1 'Change accordingly

    i = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Row
    arr1 = .Range("C1:C" & i).Value
    ReDim arr2(WorksheetFunction.CountIfs(.Range("C1:C" & i), "<>""", .Range("C1:C" & i), "<=1") - 1)

    For x = LBound(arr1) To UBound(arr1)
        If Not IsEmpty(arr1(x, 1)) And arr1(x, 1) <= 1 Then
            arr2(Countr) = arr1(x, 1)
            Countr = Countr + 1
        End If
    Next x

End With

End Sub
```

I've also implemented a dynamic last used row (instead of going through all rows) and a first initial array to avoid looping through a potential large dataset. Looping through cells or other `Range` object, which make calls to the `WorkSheet` are much slower than looping through memory.

Hopefully you understand what's going on.